# Why my DocumentSnapshot DocumentID return null in my Database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello after 2 days of testing and looking at all the StackOverflow posts I still don't understand why when I try to get my doc.ID I get null.

Its my Class to create question

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Question {
  final String id;
  final String text;
  final String answer;
  final String authorId;
  final String receiverId;
  final Timestamp timestamp;

  Question({
this.id,
this.authorId,
this.text,
this.answer,
this.timestamp,
this.receiverId
  });

  factory Question.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    return Question(
      id: doc.documentID,
      text: doc["text"],
      answer: doc["answer"],
      authorId: doc["authorId"],
      receiverId: doc["receiverId"],
      timestamp: doc["timestamp"],
    );
  }
}
```

I create question after onPress

```
 final currentUserId = Provider.of<UserData>(context, listen: false).currentUserId;
      Question question = Question(
      text: _questionController.text,
      receiverId: widget.user.id,
      authorId: currentUserId,
      timestamp: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now())
    );
    DatabaseService.sendQuestion(question: question);
```

I send data in my Database_service

```
  static void sendQuestion({Question question}) {
    questionsRef.document(question.id).collection("userQuestions").add({
      "question" : question.text,
      "receiverId" : question.receiverId,
      "authorId" : question.authorId,
      "timestamp" : question.timestamp,
    });
        DatabaseService.addActivityQuestion(question: question);
      }
```

and i create notification with addActivityQuestion

```
    static void addActivityQuestion({
    Question question,
  }) async {
     activitiesRef.document(question.receiverId).collection("userActivities").add({
        "authorId": question.authorId,
        "questionId": question.id,
        "question": question.text,
        "timestamp": Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()),
      });

  }
```

And in my Database i have this : 
result in my database i have "null" for question.id why
[image: img]

Thanks for your time, I'm still starting be indulgent it's my first post on stackoverflow :)

Comment: The value of `question.id` is probably null.  What does your debugger or logging say about that?

Comment: Yes I know nothing in the debug just it says null in the database to give because I can not insert the id of the document in the database (look at the screen) :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the question instance here

```
Question question = Question(
  text: _questionController.text,
  receiverId: widget.user.id,
  authorId: currentUserId,
  timestamp: Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now())
);
```

you don´t pass an id to the constructor, that´s why it is null.

You can get the documentID when you add a new entry to firestore like this:

```
DocumentReference docRef = await 
Firestore.instance.collection('userQuestions').add({
  "question" : question.text,
  "receiverId" : question.receiverId,
  "authorId" : question.authorId,
  "timestamp" : question.timestamp,
});
print(docRef.documentID);
```

Comment: Thank you, yes indeed but it is not possible to add the id of the document which is not yet created

Comment: I'm stuck for 4 days above it is a little annoying. If someone can help me his would help me a lot

Comment: i edited my answer and included how to get the id when you add a document.